# Why is my Math Overflow account not automatically associated with my other accounts?

Tags: support, mathoverflow, google-openid

I logged in Math Overflow and quickly went through the motions of associating it with my other accounts. Unfortunately, that is not so. My Math Overflow profile page doesn't have an "Accounts" tab either.

Or is Math Overflow not part of Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Math Overflow is part of the Stack Exchange 1.0 network, meaning it's essentially independent from Stack Overflow, SuperUser, etc., which are on the 2.0 platform.

Because of this, it's not possible to associate your accounts on Math Overflow.

<strike>Also, support questions related to Stack Exchange 1.0 sites belong on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com).</strike> (This question here is fine, though.)

**EDIT:** Meta Stack Exchange questions now belong *here*, as MSE was merged into MSO.

Comment: A similar site exists on the Stack Exchange Network called http://math.stackexchange.com/ . I think these two sites should be merged into one, since they basically serve the same purpose.

Comment: Actually, there are [differences between mathoverflow and math.stackexchange](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/41/differences-between-mathoverflow-and-math-stackexchange).